# What's more idiomatic in rent? (Pay or give the rent)

Tags: word-choice, idioms

What's more **idiomatic* * in context of rent,  to **pay** the rent or **give** the rent?

Example: 
Jon rents an appartment and he wants to say (to) his homeowner that he'll pay or give the monthly rent earlier this month.

> Hello Mr. Boris, It is Jon.  I wanted to inform you that this month I'm going to **pay** / to **give** the rent earlier,  becaause I'll not be in the city on the fixed date (by fixed day I mean to the date that every month I should pay him.)

What's more idiomatic in rent?  (Pay or give the rent) ent?  (Pay or give the rent)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Certainly you "pay" rent, usually each month, but there may be situations where "give" works, particularly to describe when you physically *hand* the rent to your landlord/landlady.

> Hi Mrs Goodwin, I'm sorry I haven't **given** you the rent for this month, I should have it by the end of the day.

In the context of your example, "pay" works better.

Side note:  You may have noticed that sometimes we say "pay rent" and other times "pay *the* rent".  When speaking in general about the requirement to pay a regular amount to live somewhere, use "pay rent"

> This is the year I'm going to buy a house.  I hate having to **pay rent**.

When talking about a specific case where you have to pay some amount, use "pay the rent".

> I really like the new management company for my condo, they let me **pay the rent** online so I never have to write another cheque.  I can even schedule **paying the rent** in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely "pay the rent". See [this ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=pay%20the%20rent%2C%20give%20the%20rent&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpay%20the%20rent%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cgive%20the%20rent%3B%2Cc0) as evidence.